# In $\mathbb{R}$ does finite mean bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

I am looking over a exercise that states "Prove that if *I* is a closed, bounded interval which is contained in the union of some collection of open intervals, then *I* is contained in the union of some finite subcollection of these intervals". Would it be safe to say, in the Real Numbers, that when he says finite subcollection you could also say a bounded subcollection?

If you could say bounded instead of finite it would give a much better jumping off point for a proof but I am not sure that the two terms are interchangeable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A finite subcollection of the collection of open intervals means finitely many of the open intervals.

This is not the same as a bounded subcollection. For instance, the set of open intervals $(1/n,1)$, for positive integers $n$, is bounded (all are contained in $(0,1)$) but not finite. And no finite subcollection will cover $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Again you can't say bounded in place of finiteness also. Consider $[2.3]$ which is contained in $\cup_{n=1}^\infty (\frac 1n,\infty) $. Then it is contained in a finite subcollection but namely $(1, \infty)$ which is not bounded, moreover any finite subcollection will not be bounded here.